# Selecting DataSource bean for use with multiple DataSourceInitializers

Tags: spring-jdbc

I have two DataSource beans and two DataSourceInitializer beans, one for each DataSource. These configurations are in different class files, but both DataSourceInitializers attempt to set up DataSourceOne.

How can I tell the DataSourceInitializerTwo to use (inject?) the DataSourceTwo bean?

```
//Data Source 1
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceOne() {
    JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:app1db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS app1\\;SET SCHEMA app1");
    ds.setUser("app1");
    ds.setPassword("app1");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializerOne(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(DatabasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

//Data Source 2
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceTwo() {
    JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:app1db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS app2\\;SET SCHEMA app2");
    ds.setUser("app2");
    ds.setPassword("app2");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializerTwo(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSourceTwo);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulatorTwo());
    return initializer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataSourceInitializer method appears to inject a DataSource bean based on parameter name. Simply make the name of your method that returns a DataSource match the name of the DataSource parameter that your appropriate initializer method takes in.

```
//Data Source 1
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceOne() {
    JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:app1db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS app1\\;SET SCHEMA app1");
    ds.setUser("app1");
    ds.setPassword("app1");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializerOne(final DataSource dataSourceOne) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSourceOne);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(DatabasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

//Data Source 2
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceTwo() {
    JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:app1db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS app2\\;SET SCHEMA app2");
    ds.setUser("app2");
    ds.setPassword("app2");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializerTwo(final DataSource dataSourceTwo) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSourceTwo);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulatorTwo());
    return initializer;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the scripts executed against them.  Somehow you need that to happen after the DataSourceInitializedEvent.  Does anyone know how to register a DataSourceInitializedEvent in a SpringBoot application?  I'm created a class that implements the interface.  I've also added the listerner to my application: SpringApplication.run(Application.class).addApplicationListener(new MyDataSourceInitializer());

Comment: This issue is unrelated to SpringBoot and DataSourceInitializedEvent. Make your own question instead of downvoting solutions to different problems.

Comment: Fair enough, they are different (but related) questions.  I'll revoke my downvote.  Followup,  (I just tried and it won't let me.  It says it's locked until the answer is edited).